# How to best take top down pictures of things organized neatly?

Tags: lighting, product-photography, shadows

I was wondering if anyone has any major tips for taking images like this:

[image]

I've tried some before but never quite managed to get that same, well lit, bright and straight shot. I also have problems with getting shadows over the items when i'm above them.

Comment: Do we know what sort of lens was used? Maybe a tilt and shift? By the way, you can see a shadow on near the top left of the backpack and some light reflected off the Voss bottle. I think that might help.

Comment: @SailorCire I know there is "shadow" in the image, I just mean if I try a similar shot I find it hard to get "above" the items without casting some sort of shadow, thus stopping me from creating a nice bright/clean image.

Comment: There's a word for this! It's called "[knolling](http://kottke.org/14/03/always-be-knolling)".

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! :) that will be enough for me to search the internet for tips and techniques.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get an image that looks straight on is to photograph it from as high as possible using a longer focal length, this greatly reduces the effect of not being quite parallel, and prevents objects in the corners from appearing to bulge outwards.

I usually use a tripod set to maximum height and a 100mm lens and shoot through the legs. If you have an indoor balcony from a floor above that would be even better.

Flat lighting is a matter of having a very soft lightsource. Window light from patio doors works well, or a flash bounced off a plain white ceiling.

Comment: Nice, I'll try these techniques out

Comment: Shooting from as high as possible will also help not block the light source and throw a shadow from you, your tripod or camera.  Having multiple light sources will help remove shadows.  Or if using window light, a reflector.

Comment: there seems to be missing something: "from appearing to ..."